# How to ListPlot two datasets on the same graph?

Tags: plotting, dataset

Consider the following dataset:

```
keys = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
vals = Partition[Range[20], 5]
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[keys, #] & /@ Transpose@vals]
```

[image]

In order to plot the first two columns (`a` being x and `b` being y) we do:

```
ListPlot[{ds[All, {"a", "b"}]}]
```

[image]

But if we want to add the last two columns as shown below, we get an error.

```
ListPlot[{ds[All, {"a", "b"}], ds[All, {"c", "d"}]}]
```

How can I plot the first two columns and the last two columns on the same `ListPlot`?

[image]

(The above plot was obtain using `ListPlot[{list1, list2}]`)

Answer (score 5):

The following seems to work:

```
ds[ListPlot @* Thread @* Values, {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}]
```

[image]

Another variation:

```
ds[ListPlot @* Values @* Transpose, {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ds[ListPlot @* Transpose, {{#a, #b}, {#c, #d}}&]
```

[image]

Slightly shorter variant:

```
ds[ListPlot[#] &, {{#a, #b}, {#c, #d}} &]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

A dirty get around this is to convert Mathematica datasets to lists and plot it:

```
ListPlot[{Normal@Values@ds[All, {"a", "b"}], 
  Normal@Values@ds[All, {"c", "d"}]}]
```

[image]